# how do i get user info in classed based view

Tags: django, django-views

I tried the solutions I could find, but it's still not working. **I need to get the info of the user that is signed in.**

here is the class-based view :

```
class networthChart(APIView, View):  
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        labels = []
        default_items = []
        user = self.request.user
        networth_history = user.networthTracker.objects.filter(user = user)
```

the error I get it:

> AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute
> 'networthtracker'

why is it returning AnonymousUser? I have used the same code in a **function-based view before and it works**

Comment: you need to log in or check if the user is not anonymous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

you need to check if the user is authenticate or not.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

class networthChart(APIView, View):  
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        labels = []
        default_items = []
        if not self.request.user.is_active:
           return HttpResponseForbidden() # any error you want to display    

        user = self.request.user
        networth_history = user.networthTracker.objects.filter(user = user)
```

more about django auth https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/